# In C# does property pattern matching allocate objects behind the scenes?

Tags: c#, .net, pattern-matching

Consider this simple class

```
public class MyData
{
   public int Count;
}
```

And this simple method that dislikes the number 10.

```
public bool IsDataValid(MyData data)
{
  return consumerData is not { Count: 10 };
}
```

Is there an object allocation happening as part of the pattern matching?
Does pattern matching do anything that would cause the check above any less performant than `consumerData != null && consumerData.Count != 10` ?

I checked documentation here [Pattern Matching Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching#compare-discrete-values) and here [Property Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#logical-patterns) but either there is no explicit mention of this or I went temporarily blind.

Comment: Why would it allocate an object? To be honest, the simplest way of checking what happens is to compile the code and use ildasm to look at the IL...

Comment: https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFDKgZgASwwWQJ4AiAhgC5HIDeyGN6GAlgHYkYDCA9gK7MDc1NWTACN27ADYYAkgGdiZAGpEx9YAAp8cohmCkiASn40qSAQKgB2bbobSMjdiwpsuzEBjgAGDAF8+Jgd7IgUhAA===

Comment: @JonSkeet To me it wouldn't make sense to allocate an object for such simple operations, but I thought there's a chance the comparisons are done by creating a new object based on the pattern behind the scenes. 
I've stumbled into cases  before where things that looked really good had some hidden costs so I thought it best to ask.

Comment: @Martheen Thank you for that. It both answers my question and it's a great resource that I'll use in the future.

Comment: @Martheen if you post your comment as an answer I will mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can [run the code through sharplab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABAzAAgwJhwFkBPAEQEMAXCgWACgBvBnV7HASwDsqcBhCAFceAbgYBfBgRwAFBs3qs2uYBAgAbHAEkAzpRoA1Cuo4ATABSl9FHKeoUAlCyUKlSjAHZb9zjpxcIXkZ+IR4QHABGAAYccTFFJUl6cSA=), and see what happens; if we use the C# output, we can see the effective code:

```cs
    public bool IsDataValid(MyData data)
    {
        return data == null || data.Count != 10;
    }
```

so: nothing scary there. We can also look at the IL:

```
    .method public hidebysig 
        instance bool IsDataValid (
            class MyData data
        ) cil managed 
    {
        .custom instance void System.Runtime.CompilerServices.NullableContextAttribute::.ctor(uint8) = (
            01 00 01 00 00
        )
        // Method begins at RVA 0x20a5
        // Code size 20 (0x14)
        .maxstack 8

        IL_0000: ldarg.1
        IL_0001: brfalse.s IL_000f

        IL_0003: ldarg.1
        IL_0004: ldfld int32 MyData::Count
        IL_0009: ldc.i4.s 10
        IL_000b: ceq
        IL_000d: br.s IL_0010

        IL_000f: ldc.i4.0

        IL_0010: ldc.i4.0
        IL_0011: ceq
        IL_0013: ret
    } // end of method P::IsDataValid
```

which is just some branching and comparisons - no `newobj` or `box`; all good. No allocations. The C# compiler team try to do things very efficiently.